# Is there a mathematical branch, that explores properties of the "dx" in terms of algebra?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

I'm currently studying multivariable calculus and started to think of some properties of dx in its infinitesimal world that can seems obvious, but the more I think of them the more powerful and strange they seems to me. So I'm wondering is there a branch that extends the ideas of the infinitesimal world(e.g. no matter how many dx you'll add to the point on the function, you'll still be in the same point) in terms of algebra. I feel that there can be a lot of intrinsic properties of infinitesimals which absent in the calculus books but can help to better understand all the things that happens in calculus. It seems to me that it is possible to construct an algebraic structure of infinitesimals and numbers to describe rules of differentiation and integration.

The question is: "What mathematical branch describes differentiation, integration, and properties of 'dx' in terms of algebraic structures or something similar?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you want to learn "[nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis)". This is a branch of analysis that formalizes infinitesimals.  But if you are just learning calculus, I'd advise against this is as it is... nonstandard.  "standard" calculus does not have infinitesimals. Only limits.

Comment: The field of differential forms makes the use of $dx$ precise. You can find introductory notes here https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/preprints/diffforms.pdf (I just googled searched 'differential forms'). You can probably find better texts if you look for recommendations.

Comment: Depending on what you are asking, you may be interested in a recent paper of mine, "Total and Partial Differentials in a Multivariable Context".  https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958 .  You also may be interested in an essay of mine, "The Interpretation of Total Differentials in a Multivariable Context", https://journals.blythinstitute.org/ojs/index.php/preprint/article/view/85 and also "Simplifying and Refactoring Introductory Calculus" https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03459 .

Comment: Thank you all for the links and recommendations. Also, @johnnyb, the last link you sent seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Then there is the algebra of (truncated) Taylor series, which formalizes Leibniz's idea and use of the infinitesimal $dx$. Differential algebra also exists, where some of the generators of the algebra are derivations. I have seen that in the context of the index theory of differential-algebraic equations (here "algebraic" means all the stuff that is not differential, not just polynomials)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up multilinear algebra, especially exterior powers of vector spaces (or modules). That is the algebraic part. The geometric part goes under the label of cotangent bundle, or more generally vector bundle: differential forms on a manifold (generalizations of dx on the real line) are related to exterior powers of the cotangent bundle of the manifold.

There is nothing truly infinitesimal here, despite the historical motivation from that direction, but it is the mainstream way concepts like dx were made rigorous for mathematicians who use them in their geometric or analytic work.